no speakable text present and Failed to instantiate one mr more classes
In the following code I am getting the following errors:
tabLayout <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>: No speakable text present
Failed to instantiate one or more classes
I have looked online and all the similar issues pertain to edittext and not having a description in those fields, however my issue is with tablayout and I have no edittext in the code.
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- TabLayout for Start, History, Settings -->
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
        app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black" />

    <!-- ViewPager2 for swiping between fragments -->
    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="700dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

Here is my main activity file
What I tried is listed above
package com.example.sahir_sood_myruns1

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // Declare variables for TabLayout, ViewPager2, and the adapter
    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var viewPager2: ViewPager2
    private lateinit var adapter: FragmentPageAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)  // Set the content view to your XML layout

        // Find the TabLayout and ViewPager2 in the layout by their respective IDs
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2)

        // Initialize the adapter with the FragmentManager and the lifecycle
        adapter = FragmentPageAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        // Add tabs to the TabLayout, each with a title (Start, History, Settings)
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Start").setContentDescription("Start Tab"))
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("History").setContentDescription("History Tab"))
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Settings").setContentDescription("Settings Tab"))

        // Set the adapter for the ViewPager2 so it knows which fragments to display
        viewPager2.adapter = adapter

        // Add a listener to handle user interaction with the TabLayout (i.e., when the user clicks on a tab)
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            // This method is called when a tab is selected
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                if (tab != null) {
                    // When a tab is selected, update the ViewPager2 to show the corresponding fragment
                    viewPager2.currentItem = tab.position
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                // This method is called when a tab is unselected, but nothing happens in this case
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                // This method is called when a tab is reselected, but nothing happens in this case
            }
        })

        // Add a callback to handle page changes in the ViewPager2 (i.e., when the user swipes between pages)
        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            // This method is called when a new page is selected
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                // When the page is changed, update the TabLayout to highlight the corresponding tab
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position))
            }
        })
    }
}


